# Problem with imageJ api using imjoy-core in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imagej

Im trying to make a simple image operation with imageJ, but ImageJ.JS argument isnt working when connecting to imjoy api.

```js
import * as imjoyCore from 'imjoy-core'

export const consoleImjoyCore = async () => {
  const imjoy = new imjoyCore.ImJoy({
    imjoy_api: {}
  })

  console.log('imjoy', imjoy)

  imjoy.start({ workspace: 'default' }).then(async () => {
    const ij = await imjoy.api.getPlugin("ImageJ.JS")
    console.log(ij);
  })
}
```

This code gives me error **Uncaught (in promise) Plugin not found: ImageJ.JS** and logs null. It works if I call Jupyter-Engine-Manager  plugin instead.

I've tried many different ways of using this api, including passing `{src:"https://ij.imjoy.io/"}` as argument, changing `getPlugin` to `createWindow` and `getWindow`. None of them worked. Also tried using just javascript and html by using this imjoy script:
`<script src="https://lib.imjoy.io/imjoy-loader.js"></script>` and calling `loadImJoyCore`, which it also didnt work.

When I tried replicating the code in Chrome DevTools, in ij.imjoy.io, using imjoy instance in window, it worked as expected, even by using the same method as the function above (`...getPlugin("ImageJ.JS"...`)

I should also say im running the application in my localhost, not in production.

Comment: Just curious: What kind of Image-processing are you trying to do and why can't you just use plain ImageJ for this purpose?

Comment: Basic image operations (subtraction, threshold...). Cant use plain ImageJ, because my application is running on the web.